# Why the following C# program uses limited (10) number of threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Why the output for the following program is always 10 threads? I tried to change the max number of threads to the thread pool to 500 but it doesn't change anything.

[image]

```
class Program
{
    private static object _locker = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var data = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();

        Parallel.For(0, 100000000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 500 },
            i =>
            {
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    if (!data.ContainsKey(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
                    {
                        data.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}, {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    }
                }
                
            });
    }

}
```

Comment: It will never use more threads than your computer has CPU cores. There is no reason to use more threads than that (within `Parallel.For`)

Comment: Also, your use of `lock` completely defeats the point of using Parallel.For!!! Use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead.

Comment: @Dai Operating System threads and CPU cores is not the same thing. You can have more OS threads than CPU cores. Tons of threads if you want. OS manages that with the CPU. The number of cores only allow to execute CoreCount *CPU instructions* at exactly the same time in parallel in the hardware pipes. https://www.guru99.com/cpu-core-multicore-thread.html & https://www.techsiting.com/cores-vs-threads/

Comment: @OlivierRogier If the CPU has 10 threads (either from 10 cores or likely 5 cores with 2 threads each), at any given time, 10 threads will be active. Windows usually has thousands or even dozens of thousands of threads, doesn't mean they are active though.

Comment: As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_MaxDegreeOfParallelism) say, this setting is designed to **limit** the number of threads used - _By default, For and ForEach will utilize **however many threads the underlying scheduler provides**, so changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from the default only **limits** how many concurrent tasks will be used._

Comment: @Dai, but I have only 4 cores on my laptop. So how can 10 threads to be run?

Comment: Could you try calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500);` at the start of the program, to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias see what I get: https://prnt.sc/uk7rg3

Comment: I voted to reopen because this is a *why* question, while the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442750/increase-number-of-running-thread-in-parallel-for) is a *how* question.

Comment: @Igor I use “CPU core” as shorthand for “hardware thread” - if you have HyperThreading enabled then each CPU core is capable of running two threads concurrently (though the second hardware thread in each CPU core runs with less performance). So 4 modern CPU cores will give you at least 8 threads. I admit I don’t know where the other two threads are coming from  but I suspect the ThreadPool adds 2 more threads if it detects underutilisation which would be caused by your `lock` statement.